# 400 bad request in google translate free api using curl

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, http-status-code-400

I am trying to use free Google Translate API which is extracted from Firefox's S3 Google Translator addon, ie.

```
https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&
tl=en&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t
&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&srcrom=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&q=Hello
```

in PHP cURL ie.

```
$isPOST=isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST);
$q=$isPOST ? $_POST['q'] : $_GET['q'];

$url='https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single';
$data='client=t&sl=auto&tl=en&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&srcrom=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&q='.$q;
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, !$isPOST ? $url.'?'.$data : $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
if($isPOST){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}
$return=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am calling this page using ajax..

```
$.ajax({
    type: text.length>750 ? 'post' : 'get',
    url: 'translate.php',
    data: 'q='+text,
    success: function(d){ alert(d); }
});
```

but doing this all, I get this response from Google Translate, ie.

```
Error: 400. That’s an error.
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.
```

Please, help me solve this error and get the translated text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I tried to POST with same code and it worked..
Thank all.

Comment: Good to hear , Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I checked your URL in your browser it shows 400 Error. it means illegal request.
try http://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/ this URL.

```
<?php
    $apiKey = '<paste your API key here>';
    $text = 'Hello world!';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=en&target=fr';

    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);                 
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($handle);

    echo 'Source: ' . $text . '<br>';
    echo 'Translation: ' . $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
?>
```

Comment: but if you see S3 Google Translator Firefox plugin source, its using same url to translate the text...

Comment: also, if you try to open the url ie. https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&tl=en&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&srcrom=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&q=Hello, then it'll give the translation in a txt file, so its working...

Comment: The problem is simply to url_encode the data.. i had the same issue, and I fixed it by simply url_encoding the data and leaving the method as GET. that's why it's working from the browser because anything you paste in the addressbar is url encoded before being posted

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in a Visual Basic 6 Project and Thamaraiselvam's comment guided me to the correct direction.. 
I was building the URL correctly and if I try it in the browser it works, but in the http component of vb6 it wasn't working. the solution was to simply url_encode the data sent. (putting it in the browser was automatically doing it)

hope this helps someone else.